# Populating a model with a LINQ outer join result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to populate a model with the result from a LINQ outer join but I'm getting the following error:Cannot implicitly convert anonymous IEnemerable to list.

I have the following model:

```
public class adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM
{
    public Product product { get; set; } // will be populated from Products table
    public PricelistProduct pricelistProduct { get; set; } // will be populated from PricelistProducts table
}
```

And this is the query:

```
adminEditPricelistVM.adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVMs = 
          from product in products
          join pricelistProduct in pricelistProducts 
            on product.ProductId equals pricelistProduct.ProductId into gj
          from subpricelistProduct in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new  { product.Name };
```

What would be the proper way to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert an enumerable of an anonymous type to a list of type `adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM` which wont work. You need something like the following:

```
adminEditPricelistVM.adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVMs = 
                (from product in products
                 join pricelistProduct in pricelistProducts 
                   on product.ProductId equals pricelistProduct.ProductId into gj
                 from subpricelistProduct in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new adminEditProductsPricelistProductsVM() 
                 {  
                     Product = product,
                     PricelistProduct = subpricelistProduct
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! However PricelistProduct = pricelistProduct is giving me a "does not exist in the current context" error. Should it be  PricelistProduct = subpricelistProduct ?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be `subpricelistProduct`